# PWA Shrinking Issue on desktop (Angular)

Tags: pwa-chrome

I'm currently working on a project that utilizes Angular, and I have incorporated a Progressive Web App (PWA) into it. However, I'm encountering an issue with the PWA window continuously shrinking when minimized. Interestingly, I don't experience any problems when maximizing the window.

I was wondering if anyone could provide assistance with this issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

[image]

Comment: Please provide a screen recording that demonstrates the issue.